# Loan calculator program

Tags: python

So far I have been coding this all week trying to get it to work.

It should come out as this:

```
Please enter Amount that you would like to borrow(£): 4000
Please enter Duration of the loan(Years):2
Please enter the interest rate (%):6
The total amount of interest for 2 (years) is: £480.00
The total amount of the period for 2 (years) is £4480.00
You will pay £186.67 per month for 24 months.
Do you wish to calculate a new loan payment(Y or N)
```

Code:

```
monthlypayment = 0  #Variable
loanamount = 0 #Variable
interestrate = 0 #Variable
numberofpayments    = 0   #Variable
loandurationinyears = 0 #Variable

loanamount = input("Please enter the amount that you would like to borrow(£) ")
loandurationinyears = input("How many years will it take you to pay off the loan? ")
interestrate = input("What is the interest rate on the loan? ")

#Convert the strings into floating numbers
loandurationinyears = float(loandurationinyears)
loanamount = float(loanamount)
interestrate = float(interestrate)

#Since payments are once per month, number of payments is number of years for the loan
numberofpayments = loandurationinyears*12

#calculate the monthly payment based on the formula
monthlypayment = (loanamount * interestrate * (1+ interestrate)
                    * numberofpayments / ((1 + interestrate) * numberofpayments -1))

#Result to the program
print("Your monthly payment will be " + str(monthlypayment))
```

Comment: So what errors appear? Also, you should probably divide your interest rate input by 100.

Comment: it basically will be an obscured amount of numbers like ill do 6, 2 , 6 and itll come up with something like 6056235.14291821421542

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix the grammar and make it better readable. Also, I corrected a presumed typo in the wanted output (`&` -> `£`). Please [edit] your question to include the complete actual output or the code as posted, so that we have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me like the only thing you're missing in the code above from what you described is a while loop. This will allow your program to calculate the loan and run the program over and over again until the user inputs no, in which case the program exits. all what you have to do is:

```
YorNo = input("Do you wish to calculate a loan payment")
YorNo.Title()

while YorNo != "n":


    #Your code goes here


    YorNo = input("Do you wish to calculate a loan payment")
    YorNo.Title()
print("Thank you for using the program")
```

In case you dont understand this, baisically, you type the first 3 lines just before your code. Then you leave an indentation and type your code after them. Once your done, you type in the 3rd and 4th line. Then, simply go back that indentation (to show the program that this isnt part of the loop.) If im not mistaken, the result of this will be:

1. You will be asked wether you want to calculate a loan
2. If you answer "y" your code will run and the loan will be calculated and printed to the user
3. Then you will be asked again. The above will repeat until you input "n"
   the N cant be capitalised

Comment: When ever i do the equation it come up with a sum of around 2555+ the amount what is needed